# Frontend form with relation to an entry

Tags: entries, relations, form, entry, entries-field

I have a field called "assetId" from Entry "A" with Field Type "Entries" and Source "B". How can I build a form so that a relation between these two entries will be established.

In the craft backend I can add a new entry in Entry "A" and can use the Button "Add an entry" to select the suitable Entry from "B". This works fine. A record is written in the Table craft_relations.

How can I build a user form in the frontend to get this. I tried following form with a hidden field "fields[assetId]" which is set to the id of the suitable content:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="send-form" id="send-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="34">
    <input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[assetId]" value="1478" id="hidden-assetID">
    [... some more fields ...]
     <input class="btn-vote" type="submit" value="send">

</form>
```

The entry is saved correctly, but without the assetId. There is no relation between targetId 1478 and the new entry in the Table craft_relations established. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After research with lots of trail & error I found the solution. I just had to add [] to my hidden field to establish the relation:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[assetId][]" value="1478" id="hidden-assetID">
```

The leading hint was here: [Setting User field type from a front end form](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8536/setting-user-field-type-from-a-front-end-form)